# Rails save tempfile to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm trying to save a pdf to S3 by using a tempfile. I'm sure the pdf is being created correctly because I use the same code to email pdfs.

A file is being saved to S3, but it's empty.

pdf is created by CombinePDF.new - so, pdf contains the pdf data.

This is my code:

```
@file = Tempfile.new('costprojectspdf')
@file.write(pdf)
@obj = @bucket.objects.create("costprojects.pdf", @file.read)
```

Is @file.read correct?
Do I need to @file.close?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you dont need `@file.write(pdf)`

Comment: pdf is the pdf object. How would I get that data into the tempfile?

Comment: Why not `File` why `Tempfile` ?

Comment: Which version of the AWS SDK (or other gem) are you using?

Comment: I thought using tempfile, that the file would locally go away.  How would I code it using file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pdf` is the raw data then this should be fine:

```
@obj = @bucket.objects.create("costprojects.pdf", pdf.to_pdf)
```

Comment: :data must be provided as a String, Pathname, File, or an object that responds to #read and #eof?

Comment: So, I figured, I'd have to save it as a file first, then save to S3.

Comment: Updated my answer. It looks like `pdf` is an instance of `CombinePDF` rather than the raw data.